# Trying to Get Graphs to Stick Together in R

Tags: r

I've been trying to get my 12 R plots on the bottom row to stick to each other (0 margins) with

```
layout(matrix(c(rep(1,10),2:11),nrow=2,byrow=T),width=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1)
plot(1:10, xaxt='n',yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, mar=c(0,0,0,0))
plot(1:10, xaxt='n',yaxt='n', ann=FALSE, mar=c(0,0,0,0))
.
.
.
```

To my knowledge, with mar=c(0,0,0,0), all the margins should be zero. But as you see there are large spaces between the plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Margins should be set inside the function `par()` after `layout()` not inside the `plot()` call.

```
layout(matrix(c(rep(1,10),2:11),nrow=2,byrow=T),width=c(1,2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1))
par(mar=c(0,0,0,0))      
plot(1:10, xaxt='n',yaxt='n', ann=FALSE)
......
```